# Dynamics CRM Online - Modifing an existing report

Tags: report, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I am trying to modify an existing report (Orders) and I must be doing something wrong because when I export the report and I open it in Visual Studio I don't see the actual report.

[image]

As you can see the actual report is not being displayed.

I go to the report entity in Workplace, select the report and click on Edit. From there I go to More Actions and click on Download Report. I then go into SQL Server Data Tools and create a Report Server Project. I then go to the Report folder, right click and Add Existing Item, selecting the order.rdl file.

What am I doing wrong?

.....

After some more research it's my understanding that none of the queries come down as FetchXml but as SQL statements that have to be converted to FetchXml.

One problem That I'm having is the use of a function. How does that get converted to FetchXml?
SELECT    fullname
FROM      FilteredSystemUser
WHERE     (systemuserid = **dbo.fn_FindUserGuid())**

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you environment is `Dynamics CRM Online`, this means that you need to create your reports only with `FetchXML`, no `SQL` reports are allowed.

The second problem is that you want to modify a built-in report , because most of the standard reports (I'm not sure if all the reports but `Order` is one of them) are built using `SQL` you can't modify and import back, you need to recreate using `FetchXML`.

Last thing, the report you opened refers to a sub report (stored in a separate `rdl` file)

Comment: I understand it is a sub report (what is a sub report?). That's the way it comes down. Are you saying that I would have to build a completely new report? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to create a new report with FetchXML

Comment: @GuidoPreite what would be a reason for the report showing NO DATA in crm online whereas showing plenty of data within VIsual Studio?